# Debugging a Service main thread

Tags: android, debugging, service

If I set up breakpoints and the Service main thread stops there, the whole Service process is shut down by Android after some seconds (around 5). Also almost no operation is possible when this happens (cannot evaluate expressions, cannot see current context variables, etc...). If it's not the Service main thread, then there's no problem, debugging works just fine.

The Service is launched through an Activity.

So, is there a way to debug a Service main thread without Android killing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments on downvotes are welcome so I can improve my question if anything is wrong, thanks :)

Comment: what are your service doing? i have a service that i use to connect ws ... is it your case?

Comment: My service performs different stuff, too much to list all here. Why is this relevant?

Comment: because, i had some problems with service when i debug, because i was pausing thread , ... and android kill it (throw an exception and kill it)

Comment: In my case no exception is thrown. And looks like Service is not killed, but debugger is detached without any reason.

Comment: can you paste some part of code? do you use starservice or startbound?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code. Code works fine when not debugging. When debugging, if I put a breakpoint, and it stops there, ADB disconnects after some time. This is the problem. I use `Context#startService`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33354/discussion-between-alex-muni-and-m0skit0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No not if you MUST use the main thread. That said there are a few ways to make it not run on the main thread, depending on how you use the service.

in case you run from onStartCommand:
Run you process in an executor (in a different thread) or use in intent service which will automatically do this for you.
In case you are using onbind:
The same applies, run it in the background, but intentservice can't help you with this. If this is the case let me know I'll show you how to do this.

Update:

There may be one development option that could help you, in the development options of your device, enable show all ANRs. This could potentially show an ARN when you block the services main thread instead of just killing it (this option exists on my phone running android 4.1.2)

If that doesn't work you could use this hack:

As you can't change the code of that service itself, you could try the following which is a bit messy and hackish. can't guarantee it'll work but it may be worth a shot.

Create a new service extending IntentService. Inside in onCreate create a wrapped service extending the service you want to debug. Like this. save this as a variable and call all your lifecycle methods on it. Except onStartCommand

```
mWrappedService = new YourServiceClass() {

    {
            attachBaseContext(WrappingService.this);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public Context getBaseContext() {
        return WrappingService.this;
    }        
}
```

In this example WrappingService is your new class and YourServiceClass is the service you are trying to debug.

Then in your onHandleIntent call the services onStartCommand method. This should work as long as the service class is not final.

Now you can at least debug this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm looking for a way to make it stop at main thread. I know I can stop at other threads and already tested it and it works fine, but this a fixed Service I cannot modify.

Comment: I updated my comment with more suggestions, if this does not work, I am afraid there is no way to do this

Comment: I don't see how an ANR notice could help with my problem... But the Service wrapping is a nice suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Because of the ANR you could tell android to wait for the service to respond instead of killing the service

Comment: Even though it doesn't solve the question, your answer offers creative solutions I didn't consider, so I give you the bounty ;)